# How Many Sorcery Points Should This Homebrew Metamagic Cost?

Tags: dnd-5e, metamagic, homebrew-review

I'm back with another homebrewed thing. But, I can't decide on a reasonable cost for it. See below:

> #### Sharpened Spell
>
> You spend **X** Sorcery Points. You modify a spell with a range that
> is not Self or Touch, has a casting time of 1 action, and a duration
> of Instantaneous.
>
> The spell you cast changes in the following ways:
>
> - If the spell forces a save DC, roll a spell attack instead. You deal 0 damage on a miss. If you hit, multiply the damage dealt by 1.25
> - If the spell is not single target, it becomes a single target spell. If the spell has area effects, it only affects the single target of
>   the spell. If it also deals damage, multiply the damage by 1.5

The idea is to maximize the damage dealt by turning your normal spell into an attack spell against a single target -- basically trying to turn every spell into Disintegrate.

### Justification of 50% Damage Boost

So that people don't pass too quick a judgement off this as possibly "too powerful" or "too weak," I'd like to break down the numbers here.

I based the 50% damage increase off of the One Target vs Multiple Targets table in the DMG.

DMG pg. 284

> #### Spell Damage
>
> | Spell Level | One Target | Multiple Targets |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Cantrip | 1d10 | 1d6 |
> | 1st | 2d10 | 2d6 |
> | 2nd | 3d10 | 4d6 |
> | 3rd | 5d10 | 6d6 |
> | 4th | 6d10 | 7d6 |
> | 5th | 8d10 | 8d6 |
> | 6th | 10d10 | 11d6 |
> | 7th | 11d10 | 12d6 |
> | 8th | 12d10 | 13d6 |
> | 9th | 15d10 | 14d6 |

The DMG says you can create a new spell with damage appropriate for its level by keeping the mean value of its damage around the same as the mean values of the dice shown in the Spell Damage table.

DMG pg. 283

> **Spell Damage**
>
> You can use different damage dice than the ones in the table, provided
> that the average result is about the same. Doing so can add a little
> variety to the spell. For example, you could change a cantrip's damage
> from 1d10 (average 5.5) to 2d4 (average 5), reducing the maximum
> damage and making an average result more likely.

On average, the mean values for single target spells according to that table is 50% higher than multiple target spells, so to compensate for the fact that this spell forces a multi-target spell to become a single-target one, the damage is scaled up by that amount.

### Justification of 25% Damage Boost

If saving from a spell successfully causes you to take half damage, then its maximum possible damage is 25% weaker. The Spell Damage table assumes you take half damage on a successful save, but advises increasing the damage by 25% if targets take no damage from a save.

DMG pg. 283

> **Spell Damage**
>
> For any spell that deals damage, use the Spell Damage table to
> determine approximately how much damage is appropriate given the
> spell's level. The table assumes the spell deals half damage on a
> successful saving throw or a missed attack. If your spell doesn't deal
> damage on a successful save, you can increase the damage by 25
> percent.

Since this spell forces you so that your targets take no damage if your attack roll misses, I compensate by boosting damage up 25%

### Closing Remarks and Dilemma

This metamagic changes the way the spell is cast while trying to abide by fair tradeoff rules according to the DMG. This probably gives it a minimum cost of at least 1 SP (and not a higher minimum) because the trade off is fair.

However, it does have a significant benefit. It replaces save DCs with spell attack rolls. This lets you use things like Advantage and Inspiration on your roll to boost your attack. It is not necessarily a strong effect, but with the right party/preparation, I think it can be.

My dilemma is, I can't decide the appropriate total SP cost. I can't seem to find a spell that provides similar advantages to form a basis.

Remembering that 1 spell slot = 1 SP, how many SP should this metamagic cost?

Comment: As written, you would never use this for damage. This bypasses saving throws, so you can skip directly to inflicting conditions. Blindness, no save? Yes please.

Comment: @fectin "If the spell forces a save DC, roll a spell attack instead." You have to overcome the target's AC for the blindness to hit, instead of them succeeding a saving throw. If you hit, then yes, they are blinded without a save.

Comment: @fectin Actually, Darkness has a duration that is not Instantaneous, so this metamagic doesn't work with it.

Comment: I'm confused; do both points apply at the same time? Where does this leave Fireball? Its a save normally so it now becomes an attack roll and the damage increases by 1.25 on a hit, but it is also an area of effect so it only hits one target but its damage increases by 1.5...? Is that cumulative?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

How many Sorcery Points should this cost? Lots. At least 5, since this metamagic is better than Careful Spell, Empowered Spell and Heightened Spell combined. I'm sure you can see where I'm going with this - it's too powerful to put a realistic cost on it.

Your new metamagic option does 3 things. The first is pretty simple - it multiples damage by 1.25, or 1.5 if it's an AoE spell. I'm going to look at *Fireball* (a pretty classic damage spell) as a standard example.

A *Fireball* does 8d6 damage, averaging 28 damage. An Empowered *Fireball*, assuming a Charisma of 20, does 8d6 with the option to reroll up to 5 dice, for an average of 31.75 damage. A Sharpened *Fireball* does 8d6 * 1.5 damage, for an average of 42 damage.

At this point, you might be thinking "But *Fireball* does 8d6 damage, where the entry in the Spell Damage table for a 3rd-level spell is only 6d6!" Unfortunately, the advice in the Spell Damage table bears little or no resemblance to the spells that were actually published.

Note that this is also the case for single-target spells. *Disintegrate* (which uses a saving throw, not an attack roll) deals 10d6 + 40 (average 75), Empowered *Disintegrate* deals 10d6 with up to 5 rerolls + 40 (average 78.75), and Sharpened *Disintegrate* deals (10d6 + 40) * 1.25 (average 93.75).

At any rate, hopefully you can see how Sharpened Spell is considerably more powerful than Empowered Spell.

Moving on, the second thing Sharpened Spell does is change the target making a saving throw into the caster making an attack roll. Ostensibly, this is a loss in damage, since most (though not all) spells that use saving throws deal half damage on a successful save. However, it is **far** easier to make an attack roll hit than it is to make an enemy fail their saving throw.

Firstly, it's a trivial matter to give yourself advantage on an attack roll; it's an extremely non-trivial matter to give an enemy disadvantage on a saving throw. For example, you have inspiration, *True Strike*, the Help action, the Hide action, The Wild Magic Sorcerer's Tides of Chaos, and heaps of other things to give yourself advantage on a roll. To give disadvantage, you have Heightened Spell, or *Contagion*. There's not many, and they require significantly more expensive resources than the advantage options.

Secondly, most powerful monsters (the kind that would be worth sharpening a spell for) have Legendary Resistance, which makes it impossible to make them fail their saving throws, since they can just say they didn't. You can make them burn through their uses of this feature, but if they're smart they'll only use it on your best spells.

Finally, attacks are (by design) easier to hit. Everyone uses attacks, and some characters use them exclusively, so monsters can't be impossible to hit without making some players feel useless. On the other hand, not everyone uses saving throws, and everyone can still function without them. It's difficult to prove this mathematically, but anyone can quickly observe that there are extremely few monsters with AC above 20.

A mid-level sorcerer (let's say level 8) with maxed Charisma only needs to roll 12 or higher to hit an AC of 20. With advantage, which you'd better believe they'll find a way to get on their Sharpened *Fireball*, that's a 69.75% chance to hit.

The same sorcerer casting a regular *Fireball* has a save DC of 16. Let's assume the monster isn't great at Dexterity saving throws (but not too bad at them, either) and give it a +3. It has a 60% chance of failing that saving throw, which is pretty good odds for the sorcerer, but not as good as the attack roll. On the other hand, if the monster gets advantage on the saving throw (which there are a lot of ways for it to do), it has a 36% chance of failing. Not so good. And, of course, this is assuming a monster with really good AC, which is more of a worst-case scenario than a usual one.

So that's why Sharpen Spell is also better than Heighten Spell. The third thing Sharpen does is change the spell from an AoE to a single-target. This looks like a drawback, and often will be, but in those situations the sorcerer *just won't do it*. For the sorcerer to be thinking about Sharpening a spell, they'll have a priority target in mind. This lets them use *Fireball* on the Big Bad without having to worry about hurting their allies. "But they could just use a single-target spell!" Well, they could. But they have a limited number of spells known, and there are in fact no 3rd-level single-target spells. Hence, this is also better (or at least as good as) Careful Spell, albeit only when you *have* a priority target.

With all that out of the way, this is a *really* cool idea. It gives us back the Spellwarp Sniper from 3.5, which was great. Focusing *Fireball*s into concentrated beams of destruction? Awesome.

I strongly recommend going ahead with this, but removing the damage bonuses. If your players choose to use this, they know they're turning an AoE spell into a single-target spell, and they know they're adding a chance of total failure. They'll use it when those aren't problems, so you don't need to boost it because of those drawbacks.

With that change in place, I'd recommend this metamagic option costing 3 sorcery points, the same as Heightened Spell. Wait, what? I said earlier that it was better than Heightened Spell! Well, it is, but it requires the player spending additional resources to make it that way. It's trivial to give yourself advantage on an attack roll, but it's not free. You have to spend an inspiration point, or use your previous turn to cast *True Strike* or to Hide, etc.

Comment: Thanks, all good things to point out. You're right about the damage boost, I didn't notice this was stronger than two other metamagics combined. On the bit about *Dominate Person* though, that one cant be Sharpened. The duration has to be Instantaneous. That restriction was meant to remove the kind of abuse with save-or-suck spells, because those spells usually have a longer duration. Other than that, 3 SP sounds about right next to Heighten!

Comment: @markovchain I completely missed that! I'll have to see if I can find an example of a really good save-or-suck spell with instantaneous duration, but for now, I'll cut that last paragraph. This answer's way too long anyway :)

Comment: You may also want to add that it is trivial for a wild magic sorcerer to gain advantage on almost *any* d20 roll when using tides of chaos.  It is somewhat DM-dependent but still a big factor.

Comment: @LegendaryDude Someone asked me about that in chat, too; I've fleshed that paragraph out a bit with *why* it's easy to get advantage but hard to inflict disadvantage.

Comment: On Empowered AOE spells, shouldn't we assume there are two targets to hit? Making the average of the Empowered fireball 62.5?

Comment: @daze413 For a sorcerer to even be thinking about using Sharpened Spell, logically they must have some kind of priority target in mind.

Comment: @Miniman True, but for the purposes of comparing damage where the trade off is losing the _AOE capability_ of Fireball for an extra 50% damage, shouldn't the sharpened damage be compared to an actual AOE fireball that hits at least 2 targets? Just my 2 cents, I could be wrong.

Comment: @daze413 I can see where you're coming from, but if there were 2 targets the sorcerer wanted to hit, they wouldn't be using Sharpen. The tradeoff you mention doesn't really exist, because the sorcerer can choose when to use Sharpen, so they'll only use it if it's actually a good idea.

Comment: It's also worth considering that the ability to not hit your allies who are in melee makes this the opposite of a tradeoff, and in fact I should probably add that to my answer.

Comment: @Miniman Save or suck instantaneous spells: Sunburst, blinded on a failed save (but get to reroll every round); Harm, max hitpoints reduced on a failed save; and Feeblemind, damage + a straight up save or suck.

Answer (score 10):

I agree with the analysis in the other answer, but recommend taking it the other direction: **remove the first ability entirely** but keep the damage boost.

The sections of the DMG you've cited clearly show that converting a multi-target spell to single-target and adding damage is trivial and not (inherently) OP. Turning save spells into attacks, however, would be difficult to balance and would become more OP at higher levels when players have more ways to get advantage. You would possibly have to make the SP cost based on spell level.

Also, I wouldn't make my players do the effort of multiplying numbers together; that would be a deal-breaker for some. Instead, use the underlying principle in the cited table. Several of the entries effectively convert d6s to d10s, so do that. Because the DMG recommends using fewer dice when converting spells beyond 4 damage dice, the sorceror will see a slight damage jump after this point – an additional 5.5 damage on average – but sorcerers typically won't use SPs until they have 3rd level spell slots, and by that point the players are fighting single-target monsters that have over 100 HP.

Using this for status-effect-imposing area spells would normally be wasteful, since you would get fewer targets for the status effect and since those spells typically have less damage to buff. As you've suggested, this is basically a way to turn **Fireball** into (a weaker) **Disintegrate** without having **Disintegrate** in your list of known spells. IMO, this is worth 1 SP.

> **Sharpened Spell**
>
> You spend 1 Sorcery Point to focus the energy in a spell, increasing it's damage. Choose a ranged spell that could damage multiple creatures:
>
> - If the spell is an area spell, decrease the size of its effect area to a 5ft cube
> - If the spell is a targeted spell with multiple targets, choose a single target
>
> Adjust the damage by replacing d6s with d10s (e.g. **Fireball**'s 8d6 becomes 8d10)

Comment: This is a really interesting way to look at it, +1!

Comment: You could probably replace the wonky conversion table with just *N*d6 -> *N*d10. Sure, you'll be off by 1d10 for some of the higher levels, but I don't think the difference will be game-breaking. Of if you want to be conservative, tell the player to reduce *N* by one if it's greater than 3. (You can still have a table, too, it'll just look less random than the one you currently have.)

Comment: Agree this is a good suggestion too, but the table conversion doesn't look "neat" enough. Agree with @IlmariKaronen here. I chose the multiplier because I thought it was simpler -- you roll 30 damage on a *Sharpened* Spell, it becomes 45.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen I agree. I've changed my answer